# Difficulty making some sentences run randomly when I press the button

Tags: java, android, kotlin

My app was built in Java, but I decided to migrate to Kotlin because it is a more current language...
The app consists of displaying some sentences at random, and for that purpose, I used the code below, but I'm having trouble converting it to Kotlin. Someone who understands more than I could help me with this? To make the app work normally, I just need to be able to translate this code.

PS.: The attributes "frases", "frasesst" and "numerosAleatorios", are in accordance with the names I gave in the project's source code.

```
Random random = new Random(); //gerar números aleatórios
                int numerosAleatorios = random.nextInt(frasesst.length); //rodar as frases aleatóriamente quando apertar o botão

                frases.setText(frasesst[numerosAleatorios]);
```

Comment: What are you having trouble with specifically? Android Studio has commands for converting Java files to Kotlin, although it usually requires some manual clean-up after conversion.

Comment: You can just do ``frasesst.random()`` to get a random element from a collection

Comment: More current language? Java 18 came out just a few days ago, Java 19 is in the works. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history

Comment: @Robert, Android only supports up to Java 8. One of the reasons Kotlin became the primary language for use on Android is that it has more modern features but still compiles Java 8-compatible bytecode. Anyway, Java is lagging Kotlin and C# in some modern and not-so-modern improvements. (null-safety operators, inlined methods, declaration-site generic type variance, primary/secondary constructors, properties, coroutines)

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin version of the code is:

```
val numerosAleatorios = frasesst.random()

frases.setText(frasesst[numerosAleatorios])
```

Or you can directly use it like this without using a variable :

```
frases.setText(frasesst[frasesst.random()])
```

You can use Kotlin collections directly so you don't need this:

```
Random random = new Random()
```

Comment: val numerosAleatorios = frasesst.random()

frases.setText(frasesst[numerosAleatorios])

Using this variable, the error "Unresolved reference: setText" appears

Comment: @MateusVitor You should define frasesst as a TextView otherwise you can't use setText method. If you directly converted java to kotlin IDE can sometimes define it as View, not TextView. If you can't find the problem you can post your code here so we can take a look.